# Filter selected list by variable

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm on cakePHP 2. I have a problem and I need your help. Here is some code of my controller (from StudentsController.php) specifically the "edit" function:

```
$students = $this -> Student -> find('list', array(
    'order' => 'Student.name ASC'
));
$this -> set('students', $students);
```

How can I filter the list by the current student's class so the list will contain all students that has the same student's class?

I need some code like this

```
$students = $this -> Student -> find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Student.class_id' => CURRENT-STUDENT'S-CLASS),
    'order' => 'Student.name ASC'
));
$this -> set('students', $students);
```

Comment: So you have the id of the student you are editing? how are you getting the current students class id

Comment: Hi Colby, I need to replace **CURRENT-STUDENT'S-CLASS** with the correct code but I don't know :(

Comment: show your entire edit function

Comment: `public function edit($id = null) {
 $this -> Student -> id = $id;
 if ($this -> request -> is('get')) {
  $this -> request -> data = $this -> Student -> read();
 } else {
  if ($this -> Student -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
   $this -> Session -> setFlash('Student has been updated.');
   $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  } else {
   $this -> Session -> setFlash('Unable to update Student.');
  }
 }
 $students = $this -> Student -> find('list', array(
  'order' => 'Student.name ASC'
 ));
 $this -> set('students', $students);
}`

Comment: is the find going to be within edit then or are you looking for another function that displays a class list.

Comment: @Colby Guyer
How to get a class list from database table within controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to your edit function, your find should look something like this.

```
$students = $this -> Student -> find('list', array(
'conditions' => array('Student.class_id' => $this->request->data['Student']['class_id']),
'order' => 'Student.name ASC'
```

));

Comment: Thanks you very much :)
It is working as a charm.
but how $this->request->data make it work? I'm a new on cakephp :(

Comment: I highly suggest you follow the blog tutorial. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial this will clear up many of your questions

Comment: Thanks for the blog tutorial. May I ask you please to give me more resources as I hope to be a professional on cakePHP :)

Comment: Cakephp.org is your big resource, it has several sections including the bakery, videos, tutorials and api. You really just have to learn by doing it, reading, following videos and looking at the work others have done. Google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you very much and I'll follow your guides